# ERROR: typedef redefinition with different types ('unsigned short' vs '__darwin_size_t' (aka 'unsigned long'))

Tags: c, makefile

I'm trying to create a make file for my program and I keep getting this error

```
error: typedef redefinition with different types
      ('unsigned short' vs '__darwin_size_t' (aka 'unsigned long'))
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_rsize_t.h:30:32: note: 
      previous definition is here
typedef __darwin_size_t        rsize_t;
                               ^
```

I have an unsigned short in my header file named `typedef unsigned short rsize_t;` but I do not have anything named `typedef __darwin_size_t        rsize_t;` in any of my files, can someone explain to me what's happening here?

Comment: Your operating system has a type called `rsize_t` already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`typedef __darwin_size_t rsize_t;` is part of one of your operating system's header files. *You* aren't trying to define `rsize_t` twice - you are defining it once, and so is the OS.

Rename your `rsize_t` to something else.